# Load JSON file in Pig script inside Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm new to the whole Hadoop/Hortonworks/Pig stuff, so excuse me for the question.

I have installed the Hortonworks Sandbox. I'm trying to load a twitter JSON file and perform some queries on the file, but I'm currently stuck in the loading file part.

I know that I should use the Elephant-bird in order to load a JSON file (without specifying the JSON schema) with JsonLoader(), so I've downloaded the Elephant-bird from the git repo and I've included the jar file

```
Elephant-bird\repo\com\twitter\elephant-bird\2.2.3\elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar
```

inside the Hortonworks Sandbox. Here a screen shot with my Pig script:

```
REGISTER elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar;
Json1 = LOAD 'JSON/sample.tweets' JsonLoader();
DESCRIBE Json1;
STORE Json1 INTO 'tweeterOutput';
```

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot get any results from this script execution. I've tried with both `STORE` and `DUMP` commands.

Probably I'm doing many wrong things in this process flow, so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `USING` keyword:

```
Json1 = LOAD 'JSON/sample.tweets' USING JsonLoader();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Apparently that is not the only error in my code, since it's still not working :(

Comment: Do you need to fully qualify the path? `com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader();`

Comment: I've tried adding this path as well. Still nothing appears as an output when using `DUMP`. The strange thing is that if I go to the Job Browser it says that the job was successfully completed. Even though that there is a red line below.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the below

1. You need to add few more jars: elephant-bird-core-4.4.jar, elephant-bird-pig-4.4.jar, elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.4.jar, json-simple-1.1.1.jar
2. Register all of them in the script

   REGISTER elephant-bird-core-4.4.jar;

   REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-4.4.jar;

   REGISTER elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.4.jar;

   REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar;
3. LOAD 'JSON/sample.tweets' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');